# Presence of optional derived datatype components

Tags: fortran

Is the presence attribute 'inherited' to components of derived data structures? The standard says, a dummy argument is not present, if the corresponding actual argument is not present. But I am not sure, how this applies to components of derived data types as in the following example:

```
program test
  implicit none

   type some_type
     integer :: acomponent
   end type some_type

   type(some_type) :: testval

   testval%acomponent = 42

   call outer()

   call outer(testval)

contains

  subroutine outer(me)
    type(some_type), optional :: me

    call inner(me%acomponent)
  end subroutine outer

  subroutine inner(simple)
    integer, optional :: simple

    if (present(simple)) then
      write(*,*) 'simple present:', simple
    else
      write(*,*) 'simple not present...'
    end if
  end subroutine inner

end program test
```

The above example compiles and runs fine with gfortran-5, but is it standard conformant? Somehow, I can't figure it out by looking at the standard.

Comment: Since you're using gfortran, you can disable non-standard Fortran with the compiler flag `-std=f2008ts`. This allows the Fortran 2008 standard including the additions of the Technical Specification (TS) 29113 on Further Interoperability of Fortran with C and TS 18508 on Additional Parallel Features in Fortran.

Comment: @jlokimlin thanks. However, the code also compiles with that flag, at least with the gfortran 5.4 installation I have here. I am actually using -std=f2008 in the original code, though I have to admit that I didn't check this small sample code with the flag until now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example code is not conforming.

The relevant part of the Fortran 2008 standard is in 12.5.2.12p3 (5) - "A designator with it [an optional dummy argument that is not present] as the base object and with one or more subobject selectors shall not be supplied as an actual argument."

The component reference in `me%acomponent` is a subobject selector.  Similarly, if `me` was an array, an array subscript of any form would also be a subobject selector.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Somehow I was under the impression, it shouldn't be allowed but got lost when looking into the standard.